# Creating clues for a mystery subplot

Tags: technique, mystery

I am working on a story in which the characters must solve a mystery. It's a "team-building exercise" at school, in which they must work together. They are graded on how well they work together and whether they are able to solve the problem.

The exercise is a scavenger hunt where objects are hidden around the school. The teams must use their first clue to find an object which will serve as the second clue, etc. until they find the last clue and turn it in.

The problem is, I have no idea where to start. I can't think of good clues. How should I go about creating clues that will be fascinating and challenging?

Comment: Why do you torture yourself so? Why do you force yourself to write something about which, as you say, you have "no idea"? **Just write something else.** Write what flows naturally from your mind. Writing is easy and requires no effort at all.

Comment: @what The mystery isn't the point of the story. It's there to drive my characters to snoop around and get into trouble while at school, for the purposes of the main plot.

Comment: @what: "Writing is easy and requires no effort at all." - *laughs hysterically*.  I'm sure it's effortless for you, but the rest of us occasionally run into problems.

Comment: @what Writing may be effortless. Plotting may not be. Two different skills. Remember that not everyone is a pantser. Mysteries are definitely "plan ahead" stories, not discovery stories.

Comment: For me, plotting is just as effortless as writing. If you have to wring your mind to come up with plausible clues when plotting a mystery, then **you are setting yourself up for writer's block**. The moment will come, when your construction just won't come together, because you have begun to build something that does not work. For plotting, you need an integrated vision or intuition or whatever you like to call it, that guides you in your construction. If you have that vision, everything will flow naturally and *effortlessly* from it. If your ideas require effort, you lack that vision.

Comment: And with "effortless" I don't mean that I don't do research or have to draw complicated plot charts so as not to get lost. With "effortless" I mean that I always know the answer to every plot-related question. For me, the clues come from the basic idea. They are logical and there is never a question about what the clues must be. When I read FlyingPiMonster's question, I get the impression that (s)he began with the plot but has no seed-idea of what the story is supposed to be about. It is a construction without foundation.

Comment: Example: If your core idea is that two people from that team fall in love or compete about winning or one is a murderer, then the clues must come from the motivations of these two people. They are not artificial clues in a pointless easteregg hunt, but they are clues to "who dunnit" or "does he love me" or "how can I win". The clues must have ***meaning***, and they get their meaning from the seed of your story. If you have that seed, the clues will follow logically from that seed. If you don't have that seed, the whole story will be pointless.

Comment: Have you Googled "treasure hunt how to write clues"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of your objects first.

Sit down and brainstorm a bunch of *things.* Things which can be hidden reasonably well in a school. Things which might have thematic links to your characters, things which can advance the plot or character development, things which might be funny. You won't use all the things, but having a list will help.

Once you have your list, you should give your items meaning. Just jot down notes: the ballet slipper means X to Jane (and Y to Dave); the toolbox will be used later by Tanika to get to the notebook which is important to John; the violin belongs to Sebastian.

When you have a list of items and meaning, start creating links. It might help here if you print out your list and literally cut out each item/note so you can shift things around on the table. See if a pattern emerges, or a plot. You can even sketch out a rough map of your school so you can trace the movements of the characters and see if that jogs anything (like they need to find item 3 in order for item 6 to make sense when they backtrack to the band room).

After you have items, meaning, order, and a rough plot, then you should have enough content (and context) to start sketching out clues.

Comment: This really helped. I managed to think of some objects that would be really good at hiding meaning in plain sight, like receipts and broken watches.

Comment: This is another great answer because it provides specific things you can do as a writer / planner to get to a certain place with your writing.  I'm going to come back to this again later.  Thanks.